# I want to forward Apple mail to G mail account

Tags: macos, email

I am running OS X Mavericks.

I want to forward my apple mail (happens to be verizon.net) to my gmail account.

I want to read all mail in gmail.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Welcome to AskDifferent, if you provide your version of Mail I can make my answer more specific to your case.

Comment: Mail help has instructions appropriate for each version, but it's less ideal than forwarding from the server directly.

Answer (score 6):

Apple mail is just a mail client, to forward your mail to gmail, the set up needs to be done on Verizon.

You will need to log into [Verizon web mail](https://webmail.verizon.com/signin/) and then set up forwarding from there to gmail, otherwise you are forwarding your mail twice. Once from Verizon to your computer running Apple Mail and then again from your computer to google.  Depending on how good the Verizon web mail/mail server is forwarding should be easy to set up.

What you want to do is cut out your computer all together.

---

If you want to really set up forwarding from your computer i.e. from Apple Mail you would set up a rule in the following way:
While in Mail:

Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to bring up the preferences window

Select the **Rules** tab

[image]

Click "Add Rule"

[image]

Put in your "Description"

Select "Every message"

[image]

Under "Perform the following actions"

Select "Redirect Message" to put in your gmail account.

Please note that these instructions are for Mail 5.3 but should work with newer versions.

Comment: Wow....now I need to decide whether to forward from computer or Verizon....will ponder that.. great response from @bmike too. Instructions very clear. Would have mentioned current mail level but thought the Mavericks would cover it. Had no mail problems before update.Thanks all.

Comment: So did you want to mark one of the questions as accepted?

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can go in to Gmail and have it check your Verizon account like a desktop mail client. It will check your mail and remove it from the server and probably be a much easier set up than forwarding.

Comment: I would go with this option, have gmail pick up your verizon email. It works when your mac is off and as you get mail.

Comment: I did not realise that gmail had that functionality.

Comment: Yes, it is in Options - Settings - Check Mail from other Accounts. I know many people who pull all of there mail from other accounts through the Gmail interface for the spam filtering alone.

Comment: This too is a very attractive solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Apple mail.app is a client so you could set up a rule to forward mail, but that rule doesn't run when the Mac is offline.

Much better would be to log in to the web interface and forward the mail directly from Verizon's mail server directly to google.

If you are ok with your Mac doing the forwarding, the built in help has instructions on setting up your first mail rule.

Answer (score 0):

Go to iCloud. Sign in with your apple info then click on the  'mail' symbol.  You will see your Apple mail.  On the far left, at the bottom, click on the gear symbol then preferences.  An option to forward all your Apple mail to  your new mail address is there, click on that.  Done.

This worked for me just yesterday with Mac Mail and GMail.  It forwards it as it comes in.  Success!